# Java to Kotlin interface method name and field name colision (Java, Kotlin mix)

Tags: java, kotlin

Have some any tip or answer for this situation when use Java, Kotlin mix.

Java implementation

```
public interface IIdentified<ID> {
    ID getId();
}

public class SomeEntity implements IIdentified<Long> {

    private Long id;

    //Some code....

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

My convert attempt. Interface in Java, class in Kotlin. I get error from IntelliJ
*Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getId()Ljava/lang/Long;):
public final fun (): Long? defined ...
public open fun getId(): Long defined in ...*

```
//SomeEntity.kt, IIdentified.java
class SomeEntity : IIdentified<Long> {

    val id: Long? = null

    override fun getId(): Long {
        return id
    }
```

How is correct/best implementation kotlin way in this situation? I need mix Java and Kotlin Interface must stay in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [marstran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862483/7327572), but there is also another option, you can make id field private then you will not have clash error, with this approach you don't introduce another method(visible only in Java)

Sample code:

```
class SomeEntity : IIdentified<Long> {

    private val id: Long? = null

    override fun getId(): Long {
        return id ?: 0
    }

}
```

You can still use id as property in Kotlin:

```
val someEntity = SomeEntity()
val id = someEntity.id // this works
```

This would also work with properties declared in constructor:

```
class SomeEntity(private val id: Long? = null) : IIdentified<Long> {

    override fun getId(): Long {
        return id ?: 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that most likely will not be solved. See this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653

Your best bet is to use the `JvmName`-annotation to rename the getter of your `id` property. The renamed getter will only be accessed by that name from Java, while you can still use `someEntity.id` from Kotlin.
Like this:

```
class SomeEntity : IIdentified<Long?> {

    @get:JvmName("getOtherId") 
    val id: Long? = null

    override fun getId(): Long? {
        return id
    }

}
```